# Angular 6 set Background Color in Html to CSS Variable

Tags: html, css, angular

I am using Angular 6 and I have a simple `div` and want to set the background color of this `div` from inside the template. This works fine when passing normal colors. But this does not work with CSS Variables.

This example works

```
<div [style.background]="'red'">...</div>
```

This example does not work

```
<div [style.background]="'var(--some-css-var)'">...</div>
```

Answer (score 17, accepted):

You have to use ngStyle

```
<some-element [ngStyle]="{'background-color': styleExp}">...</some-element>
```

https://angular.io/api/common/NgStyle

Answer (score 7):

In order to bind a style property to a CSS variable in the HTML template, the CSS variable expression `var(...)` must be sanitized. You can define a custom pipe:

```
import { Pipe, PipeTransform } from '@angular/core';
import { DomSanitizer, SafeStyle } from '@angular/platform-browser';

@Pipe({
  name: 'safeStyle'
})
export class SafeStylePipe implements PipeTransform {

  constructor(private sanitizer: DomSanitizer) { }

  transform(value: string): SafeStyle {
    return this.sanitizer.bypassSecurityTrustStyle(value);
  }
}
```

and use it in the HTML template:

```
<div [style.background-color]="'var(--some-css-var)' | safeStyle"></div>
<div [style.background-color]="bkColor | safeStyle"></div>
```

```
bkColor = "var(--some-css-var)";
```

See [this stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-hhddnt) for a demo.

Comment: This works! But as @Gurvinder Guraya responded down below this will also work without the pipe. Should I use the pipe or `ngStyle` instead?

Comment: Your question was about setting the color with a CSS variable. The only way to make it work is to sanitize the value (with a pipe or in code). Other answers give alternatives to avoid setting the color with a CSS variable. You can obviously set the color in several ways but I tried to answer the question as it was asked, assuming that you had reasons to use CSS variables.

Comment: strangely this worked: `[ngStyle]="{ 'background-color': 'var(--dy-color-2)' }"`

Comment: Or would you recommend to do it with sanitizing the value?

Comment: Ah, OK. Sorry, I hadn't tried `ngStyle` with a CSS variable (I thought @GurvinderGuraya gave it as a workaround). You can pick the solution that you prefer then. If sanitizing is not needed with `ngStyle`, then that would be a simpler solution.

Comment: Alright, I appreciate your quick help, have a nice day!

Answer (score 5):

You can do it in 2 ways

1. use pipe that get a string and return some color code  code.

   ```
   <div [style.background-color]="someString | colorSetter"></div>
   ```
2. add to the html tag a dynamic class for example:

   `<div class="my-div" [class]="someClassName"></div>`

and in the scss add the options

scss:

```
.my-div{
    &.optoin1{
       background-color:red;
     }
&.optoin2{
       background-color:black;
     }
&.optoin3{
       background-color:green;
     }
&.optoin4{
       background-color:yellow;
     }
}
```