# Angular2-linear-gradiant bind background colour

Tags: html, css, angular

static values works perfectly

```
 <div style="background: linear-gradient(to right, #0000FF 0%, #0000FF 50%, #FFA500 50%, #FFA500 100%);"></div>
```

in my ts.

```
 this.blueColor = '#0000FF';
 this.orangColor = '#FFA500';
```

when I bind this variables in html i'm getting template error.

```
<div style="background: linear-gradient(to right, {{blueColor}} 0%, {{blueColor}} 50%, {{orangColor}} 50%, {{orangColor}} 100%);"></div>
```

how to bind variables inside of it ?

Comment: to start with you can simplify the gradient like this `linear-gradient(to right, #0000FF 50%, #FFA500 0);"`

Comment: how to bind the variable  instead of static color ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1. You can use variable also in ts:

   `blueColor = '#0000FF';
     orangColor = '#FFA500';
     background="linear-gradient(to right,"+ this.blueColor + " 50%," + this.orangColor + " 0)";`

   HTML:

   `<div [style.background]="background"></div>`

   [See code](https://stackblitz.com/edit/hello-angular-6-k11hhy?file=src/app/app.component.html)
2. **TO bind in HTML use**

   `<div [style.background]='"linear-gradient(to right,"+ this.blueColor + " 50%," + this.orangColor + " 0)"'></div>`

   [See code](https://stackblitz.com/edit/hello-angular-6-6sqxez?file=src/app/app.component.html)

Comment: shouldn´t it be 
<div [style.background]='"linear-gradient(to right,"+ blueColor + " 50%," + orangColor + " 0)"'></div>
?

Comment: i need one more help. i want to bind that variables conditionally.                       
 <div [style.background]='"linear-gradient(to right,"+ blueColor  ? blueColor : " " + " 50%," + orangColor ? orangColor : " "   + " 0)"'></div>. but it shows both side bluecolor

Answer (score 0):

You could possibly use 3 way.

First is to use `[ngClass]` then define them later on in `css` and `.ts` file as to what would you like the class would be.
Example:

`.html`

```
<div [ngClass]="class">
    <hello name="{{ name }}"></hello>
</div>
```

`.ts`

`class = 'option';`

`.css`

```
.option{
 background: linear-gradient(to right, #0000FF 0%, #0000FF 50%, #FFA500 50%, #FFA500 100%);
}
```

Second is to use `pipe` you can refer to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52282888/3654837) for more detail.

Third is to use a predefined style in the `.ts` which you could modify the variable which define the color later on.

`.html`

`<div [style.background]="background">test</div>`

`.ts`

```
  blueColor = '#0000FF';
  orangColor = '#FFA500';
  background= 'linear-gradient(to right, '+ this.blueColor+' 0%, '+ this.blueColor+' 50%, '+ this.orangColor+' 50%, '+ this.orangColor+' 100%)';
```

[Stackblitz for Demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-iqewip?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts)

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer. it works for me.

```
[style.background]="'linear-gradient(to right, ' +  blueColor +'  0%  ,  ' +  blueColor +' 50% , ' +  orangColor +'  50%  ,  ' +  orangColor +' 100% )'"
```

Answer (score 0):

You could also use angular's renderer2 to set a css variable, then use it in your css with var( --some-var ). For example in your css:

```
background: linear-gradient(to right,  var(--color-1) 0%,  var(--color-1) 50%,  var(--color-2) 50%,  var(--color-2) 100%);
```

and in your .ts, in ngOnInit :

```
  this.blueColor = '#0000FF';
  this.orangColor = '#FFA500';

  this.renderer.setAttribute(
    this.el.nativeElement, "style", `--color-1: ${this.blueColor}; --color-2: ${this.orangColor}`
  );
```

What this is doing is assigning a custom color to the css variables. You can see a working demo here :

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-stackoverflow-answers