# change background color based on ngIf

Tags: angularjs, angular, typescript, angular-ng-if

I have values coming from the server database, and I want to change the  background color based on which ngIf will appear on the view, how do I do that.?

the  background color changes based on the ngIF value ..

```
    <td>
          <div  *ngIf="obj.fruit ==3 "> Apple </div>
          <div  *ngIf="obj.fruit ==2 "> Orange </div>
          <div  *ngIf="obj.fruit ==1 "> Banana </div>
          <div  *ngIf="obj.fruit ==0 "> Cherries</div>
    </td>
```

Comment: Do you mean the `td`element?

Comment: NgStyle, ngClass

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Angular 6 set Background Color in Html to CSS Variable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52282450/angular-6-set-background-color-in-html-to-css-variable)

Comment: yes  the whole td cell backgounrd

Comment: it didn't work for me

Comment: the background color should be on <td> cell based on ngIf value

Comment: try this: [ngStyle]="obj.fruit==1 ?{background-color:'blue'}:{background-color:'red'}"

Comment: what if I've four or five ngif ?

Comment: You can try ngFor with indexes then.

Comment: can u show me please an example ?

Answer (score 3):

Here's my suggestion

```
// FruitsType.ts
export enum FruitsType {
    Apple
    Orange
    Banana
    Cherries
}

// your.component.ts
fruitColors = new Map<FruitsType, {name: string, color: string}>([
    [FruitsType.Apple, {name: 'apple', color: 'red'}],
    [FruitsType.Orange, {name: 'orange', color: 'orange'}],
    [FruitsType.Banana, {name: 'banana', color: 'yellow'}],
    [FruitsType.Cherries, {name: 'cherries', color: 'purple'}]
]);


// your.component.html
<td [style.background-color]="fruitColors.get(obj.fruit).color">
   <div>{{fruitColors.get(obj.fruit).name}}</div>
</td>
```

Also, depending on your needs this can be transformed into a Directive, meaning that you'll be able to reuse the directive without writing all this logic in each component.

Comment: what is the fruit in the html page, it's undefined

Comment: @AAaaAA Then you need a fallback. Either `fruitColors.get(obj.fruit)?.name || "I don't like fruit"` or just an ngIf to conditionally render the fruit. It depends on your particular scenario :)

Answer (score 1):

in `test.component.ts` :

```
getColor(value) {
//return class
  if(value ==3) return 'b-blue'
  if(value ==2) return 'b-red'
}
getValue(value) {
  if(value ==3) return 'Apple'
  if(value ==2) return 'Orange'
}
```

in `test.component.html`:

```
<td [ngClass]="getColor(obj.fruit)">
   <div>{{getValue(obj.fruit)}}</div>
</td>
```

Comment: it does work, if you'll create classes for each color specified. like ` .b-blue { background-color: blue; }` and so on...

Comment: hi @AAaaAA , pls add class ".b-blue { background-color: blue; }" and so on

Answer (score 0):

here it is with ngSwitch, which is equivelent to ngIf:

```
<div [ngSwitch]="obj.fruit">
 <div *ngSwitchCase="'0'" style="background-color:red"> Apple </div>
 <div *ngSwitchCase="'1'"  style="background-color:orange"> Orange</div>
 <div *ngSwitchCase="'2'"  style="background-color:yellow"> Cherries</div>
 <div *ngSwitchDefault style="background-color:gray"> Pick again</div>
</div>
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).