# Angular's source code : [style.xxx] documentation

Tags: angular

I am trying to find the source code for the `style` directive, that is used like this :

```html
<div [style.background-color]="'red'"></div>
```

Since it's usable when using `CommonModule` and it's a directive, I tried going into the [corresponding package](https://github.com/angular/angular/tree/main/packages/common/src/directives), but didn't thing anything related to it.

Would you happen to know where I can find the documentation for it ?

For information, I would like to find its source code to know how the selector works, so that I can reproduce it for custom directives. If you instead know how to do that, I'll take it instead !

I tried making a custom directive that accepts a syntax like this

```html
<div [myDir.xxx]="1"></div>
<div [myDir.yyy]="2"></div>
```

But the selector would look like this

```js
{
  selector: '[myDir.xxx],[myDir.yyy]'
}
```

And I don't want to add EVERY combination to my selector, rather a mask or something.

Comment: this link might help you : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52282450/angular-6-set-background-color-in-html-to-css-variable

Comment: No it does not. At all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`[style]` and `[class]` are not directives. They are [property bindings](https://angular.io/guide/binding-syntax#binding-types-and-targets), and those bindings are then handled by the renderer directly without any directives in between.

I haven't ever dug deep enough into the topic to find everything related to it, but parts of the relevant code are [here](https://github.com/angular/angular/blob/main/packages/core/src/render3/instructions/styling.ts) and [here](https://github.com/angular/angular/blob/main/packages/core/src/render3/styling/style_binding_list.ts).

That said, as per [docs](https://angular.io/api/core/Directive#selector), there is no way to actually use a wildcard in the css selector of the directive / component. So you're stuck with either providing finite amount of attributes in the selector (as you already do) or passing an object as the value, e.g. `[myDir]="{xxx: 1, yyy: 2}"`.